# Не могу подключить Vk Api для .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, vknet

Visual Studio 2013. В Package Manager Console пишу "Install-Package VkNet". Выдаётся следующая ошибка:

*Install-Package : 'HtmlAgilityPack' already has a dependency defined for 'Syste
m.Net.Http'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package VkNet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOper 
   ationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.InstallPackageCommand*

Чтобы понять это, у меня не хватает ума. VkNet я скачал, может, ещё что-то нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот установи последний NuGetPackageManager для Visual2013
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий пожалуйста! прими и оцени ответ плиз